# Is it possible to access an instance variable via a static method?

Tags: c#, static

In C#, is it possible to access an instance variable via a static method in different classes without using parameter passing?

In  our project, I have a `Data access layer` class which has a lot of static methods. In these methods the `SqlCommand` timeout value has been hard-coded. In another class(`Dac`) in our framework there are many instance methods which call these static methods.

I don't want to code too much using parameter passing. Do you have any other solution which is easier than parameter passing?

Comment: A static method is not associated with any instance so how do you expect it to know which instance to access a member of?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to access an instance variable from a static method without using a parameter but only if you can access it via something that is declared static. Example:

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    public int InstanceVariable = 42;
}

public class Program
{
    static AnotherClass x = new AnotherClass(); // This is static.

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x.InstanceVariable);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, but oh [the horror of global variables](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad)!

Answer (score 7):

Sure, you could pass an instance as a parameter to the method.  Like:

```
public static void DoSomething(Button b)
{
    b.Text = "foo";
}
```

But it wouldn't be possible to get at any instance variables otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

A static method has no instance to work with, so no. It's not possible without parameter passing.

Another option for you might be to use a static instance of the class (Mark's example shows this method at work) although, from your example, I'm not sure that would solve your problem.

Personally, I think parameter passing is going to be the best option. I'm still not sure why you want to shy away from it.

Comment: The edit boils down to "I don't want to", which is not a good technical reason.  The alternative is really really bad, if not impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can, as long as it has an instance of an object in scope.
Singletons for instance, or objects created within the method itself..

Take for example a common scenario :

```
public static string UserName
{
   return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.

If you want to access an instance variable then your method by definition should not be static.

Comment: What about accessing instance properties of singletons ?

Comment: @Richard: With a singleton you have an instance, and the methods would not be static in that case. Only the method to get the singleton instance is static.