# Accessing a non static DataSet in a Static method

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and am running into a problem. I want to do the following:

I have a `DataSet` named `state` wich I want to access from static methods. However the plugin im using (SpecExplorer) does not allow me to declare the instance of `DataSet` as `static`. For example:

```
// This gives a long error from SpecExplorer
static State state = new State();

// This gives no error however I am not able to use `state` in any of the static functions.
State state = new State();
```

The function im trying to access `state` in has to look like this since that is required by SpecExplorer:

```
[Rule]
static void create(int param) {
   // ACCESS STATE
}
```

I have also tried the solution suggested in:

[Accessing non static variables in static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371839/is-it-possible-to-access-an-instance-variable-via-a-static-method)
But Get the exact same error when trying this.

The error im getting says the following:

> unavaliable member in Syste.Data.DataSet.set_Namespace(System.String):
>   System.Data.Common.ADP.IsEmpty(System.String) (probably cause is incomplete type substitution).

My question is:
What is the workaround that allows me to access `state` in my static method?

Comment: Pass `state` as an additional parameter to your static `create` method. Accessing global objects like you are trying to is considered bad practice.

Comment: In your case there is only two possible solution 1. make dataset static. Which I believe your vs extension plugin is refusing and 2. make method create non static 3. provide dataset as an method parameter to Create.

Answer (score 0):

create a `static instance` of the `DataSet` holder class:

```
 class classA {
  //...
  public DataSet state;
  //...
 }
```

you can have:

```
static ClassA a=new ClassA():
[Rule]
static void create(int param) {
   //...
   a.state=//do something with it;
   //...
}
```

Comment: This would not perserve the state between function calls? I need the state to be perserved over multiple calls to create.

Comment: as the `create` is `static` then yes  it would perserve the state between function calls. (I edited the answer).

Comment: That is the solution I link to in my OP. It gives the same error.

Comment: sorry I didn't look at the link and don't know what's there, so it needs to more review, hope you'll get it fixed soon

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to pass in `state` as additional parameter:

```
[Rule]
static void create(State state, int param) {
   // ACCESS STATE
}
```

And call it from a method where you have access to the instance member.

```
State s = new State();
State.create(s, 0);
```

Or from inside a `State` instance:

```
create(this, 0);
```

Comment: I dont have control over the parameters that is passed to create, they are randomly generated by SpecExplorer.

Comment: When all efforts trying to make it work are error prone. Making an instance member static can make your life miserable, especially in ASP.NET where static is shared across all instances.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is with that `DataSet` requires non managed functions to be called during exploration. It is recommended to only use the types in `Microsoft.Modeling` when represeting state.